# know the execution time and compare execution time of 2 files using PERL or shell script

Tags: perl, shell, sh

i have to compare the last executed times of two files using perl or shell script

```
file1.txt  22:07 20-12-13
file2.txt  22:30 21-12-14
```

Want to compare which one executed latest

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -le '@r=@ARGV; print $r[-M $r[0] > -M $r[1]]' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: could you please help , the switches -E and -M doesnt work fr me

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "last executed times"? My answer works with the last *modification* time:

In shell, you can use the `-nt` and `-ot` tests:

```
if [ "$file1" -nt "$file2" ] ; then
    echo "$file1 is newer than $file2."
fi
```

In Perl, use the `-M` file test:

```
if (-M $file1 < -M $file2) {
    print "$file1 is newer than $file2.\n";
}
```